# Create new color in resource windows-8

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to create new colors with my own RGB values in windows-8.
Just like color.xml in android.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a `Color.xaml` resource dictionary as below

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBlack" Color="#000000"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then in `App.xaml` I added the following

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            ...
            ...
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Color.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And in my `Text.xaml` I have used this

```
    <TextBlock Text="How are you?" Foreground="{StaticResource MyBlack}"/>
```

**P.S.** Thanks to [Antonio Bakula](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351383/antonio-bakula) for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12890677/468724), please have look on this too.

Comment: i looks ok to me :) but I am also pretty new to Metro

Answer (score 3):

Define color like this :

```
<Page.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyCustomColor">#FFDEDEDE</SolidColorBrush>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

use it like this :

```
<TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="{StaticResource MyCustomColor}"></TextBlock>
```

If you want define your custom application style look at this :

http://www.markermetro.com/2012/07/technical/windows-8-overriding-metro-app-resources/

Comment: Thanks for your help.. It solved my problem up to some extent